# Cloud Vision Sample app failed to make API request

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am having trouble getting the Google Vision Sample App to have a successful API request.

I made sure the billing, API-key, were correct.  I even tried using a browser key and service key, but had no luck.

The error coming back is:

> failed to make API request because of other IOException Unable to
>   resolve host "vision.googleapis.com": No address associated with
>   hostname

If you have any ideas, I would surely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Solve:

Something was wrong with the Wifi on my phone.  I think it was suffering from being off.  I also changed the API-Key to Browser which is not the ideal solution, but will do for now.